# Laravel: what's the difference between schedule->call()->daily()? and schedule->job()->daily()?

Tags: laravel

What changes if I call

```
schedule->call(function() { .. do something ... })->daily()
```

and if I call

```
schedule->job(... my job class where handle do the same things... )->daily()
```

?

Comment: One has a typo, the other doesn’t.

Comment: Hahahaha... :) one has typo and other doesn't ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `job()` method is there specifically for adding a Laravel [job](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#creating-jobs) (i.e. a class that implements the `Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue` interface) to a queue. Whereas the `call()` method would run a `Closure` or an [invokable object](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke) **synchronously** at the scheduled time, the `job()` method would add the given job to a queue at the scheduled time. The queue worker would then process the job when it gets to the front of the queue which might not be immediately.

The `$schedule->job(new Heartbeat)->everyFiveMinutes();` is then basically a shortcut for:

```
$schedule->call(function () {
    Heartbeat::dispatch();
})->everyFiveMinutes();
```

Answer (score 2):

It's practically the same thing.

`$schedule->job()` requires you to create a job class and add the logic there. This is an easy way to schedule a job without having to write the execution code yourself.

Where as `$schedule->call()` allows you to do any action directly in a callback. This removes the need to create a job class for simple actions.

Answer (score 2):

job()

> The job method may be used to schedule a queued job. This method
>   provides a convenient way to schedule jobs without using the call
>   method to manually create Closures to queue the job.

source :https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#scheduling-queued-jobs

Basically, there is no significant difference for you. But writing complex code in the call method can become messy quite easily.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that one has the code in-line and the other separates it out into its own class.

The in-line option is appropriate if the code is extremely short, readable, and in context.

The separate class option is appropriate if the code is more than a couple of lines long.

In general writing clean code to the SOLID principles would dictate using the separate class option in almost every case.